# SQL query to implement multiple WHERE condition on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, tbl1 and tbl2 as below:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (`uid` int);

INSERT INTO tbl1 (`uid`)
VALUES
    (100),
    (200),
    (300),
    (400);

CREATE TABLE tbl2 (`id` int, `uid` int, `status` int);

INSERT INTO tbl2 (`id`, `uid`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1, 100, 0),
    (2, 100, 1),
    (3, 100, 2),
    (4, 100, 4),
    (5, 200, 0),
    (6, 200, 1),
    (7, 300, 0),
    (8, 300, 3),
    (9, 300, 4),
    (10, 400, 1),
    (11, 400, 2);
```

SQLFIDDLE:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a6c20/13

Problem:
I want to join these two tables.
The result should show the rows having tbl2.status = 0 but not having tbl2.status = 1.

This is the SQL query which I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.uid, tbl2.id, tbl2.status 
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl1.uid = tbl2.uid)
WHERE tbl2.status = 0
OR tbl2.status <> 1;
```

CORRECT expected result is: `7, 300, 0`.

Here, uid=300 has a row with status=0 and this uid=0 has no row with status=1. So this is the expected result that I want.

```
uid=100 has both status=0 and status=1, so this is not the required result.
uid=200 also has both status=0 and status=1 so this is not the required result.
uid=400 does not have status=0, this is not the required result.
```

Help please!!!

Comment: I'm not certain exactly what you are asking

Comment: The query is wrong but he means that he wants the uids that have only 0,2,3,4 values as status. The description is not very clear. Stop downvoting answers if you haven't understand the question.The expected result that is provided is the key to understand what;s exactly the question.

Comment: @geoandri I suspect people are downvoting answers because they say *Try this* followed by code. Those answers are not helpful because they don't explain why the code is useful or what the code does to find the solution. People vote on more than just whether an answer might be right or wrong.

Comment: That's totally acceptable but most of  other answers seem to have missed the actual question. I am not complaining though.Next time i will be much  more explanatory.

Comment: @geoandri Just edit your answer now to explain why it works.

Comment: Just did. Hope it makes it more usefull.

Comment: Solution provided by geoandri, worldofjr and RADAR works great. What will be the performance difference between the solution provided by RADAR vs (geoandri / worldofjr)

Comment: @pachabhaiya Almost certainly none. The different answers both contain one sub-query, and effectively do the same thing in the same way (just a method difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select uids with status=0 but not the ones that appear in your table also with status=1. So you need to exclude them from the result set. You need one more condition in your where clause to have the expected result. This can be done by using NOT IN.

Try the following query

```
SELECT  tbl1.uid, tbl2.id, tbl2.status 
 FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl1.uid = tbl2.uid)
WHERE tbl2.status = 0
and tbl2.uid NOT IN (SELECT uid from tbl2 where status=1);
```

Comment: To the one who down vote: have you tried it in SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a6c20/13

Comment: Just wanted to say I hope you've noticed the difference a bit of explanation can have to the usefulness of your answer. Good answer revision! +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `NOT EXISTS` clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.uid, T2.id, T2.status 
FROM tbl1 T1
INNER JOIN tbl2 T2 ON (T1.uid = T2.uid)
WHERE T2.status = 0
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl2 T22
                 where T2.uid = T22.uid
                 and T22.status =1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
OR tbl2.status <> 1
```

It is illogical (if the column equals 0 then it can't equal 1) and confuses the query.

If you want all unique `uid`s where `status` equals 0, but never equals 1, then use a subquery, with the `AND` logic;

```
WHERE tbl2.status = 0
AND tbl2.uid NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM tbl2 WHERE status=1)
```

This selects all the rows where `status` equals 0, and then removes the rows where the same `uid` has a `status` that equals 1. This will give you the expected result you gave in the question.

If you want all rows **except** those where `status` equals 1, use;

```
WHERE tbl2.status <> 1
```

Which gives you exactly the same result as the current query, the `tbl2.status = 0` is irrelevant.

Comment: The expected result should be `WHERE tbl2.status <> 1` plus there should be at least one row with `tbl2.status = 0`.

Comment: @pachabhaiya In which case you need the last of the three options in my answer. `tbl2.status = 0` is not required - it doesn't return any more or less results in any case.

Comment: your logic `WHERE tbl2.status = 0
AND tbl2.uid NOT IN (SELECT uid from tbl2 where status=1)` works great. Just one question, Is there any performance issue if there are thousands of record with status=1 ?

Comment: There's always some sort of performance loss when you add sub-queries, but this is the most efficient way to get the result you want and the difference is very small. This isn't a particularly heavy query anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic error with the OR in the WHERE clause.

The clause `WHERE tbl2.status = 0` produces the desired result:

```
(7, 300, 0)
```

The clause `OR tbl2.status <> 1` produces

```
(7, 300, 0)
(8, 300, 3)
(9, 300, 4)
```

Since this is an *OR* the union is taken, and you get all three tuples.

People new to SQL often find `OR` to be tricky. I used to keep [truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction) near me when an unexpected result confused me.

Comment: Indeed, `AND` would have made more sense, although completely not required in this case.

Comment: The SQL I posted in the description is not the correct one and I'm pretty aware of that. Keeping both AND or OR didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Putting OR doesn't make sense, just remove the OR part and Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.uid, tbl2.id, tbl2.status 
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl1.uid = tbl2.uid)
WHERE status = 0;
```